# Database does not return proper data in unit test

Tags: sql, unit-testing, updates

I am having an application for unit test. When I run the tests individually all tests behave as expected, but when I run the tests of a class altogther there are several errors.

I have a method for testing updated entries.
When I see the database the entry has been updated but when I fetch same data at the same time it returns previous value.

Following is my code

```
 //Arrange
        var Model = new Model() {
            Id = 1, 
            CategoryId = 1, 
            Host = "http://www.test1234567890host.com", 
            IsDeleted = false, 
            Title = "TestTitle1234567890test",
            Keywords = "TestKeywords1234567890test"
        };
        //Act
        var result = controller.Edit(Model) as RedirectToRouteResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(Test.Sets.Any(x => x.Id == 1));
        var SetAfter = Test.Sets.Find(1);
        Assert.AreEqual("http://www.test1234567890host.com", SetAfter.Host);
```

Host is always null even after the value has been updated in the database.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what exactly *are* the errors?

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual("http://www.test1234567890host.com", SetAfter.Host);` this assert fails because host is null when I run all the tests. But when I run only this test it passes.

Comment: Are you sure you're committing the DB change?

Comment: yes...And I can see the updated data in the table